# Changing values for ndarray based on condition upon another ndarray of the same shape

Tags: python, numpy, landsat

So I have two ndarray 
one is containing ndvi values the other one is containing temperature

The condition is that the for all the pixel with temperature that is above the 25% of all temperatures, its pixel's ndvi value has to be changed to np.nan.

So I am currently using:
temp[temp > T_25]=np.nan (which only sets the temp to nan)
I just need to look for the index in the above and apply to ndvi?

I tried to flatten it and use np.where(temp[temp > T_25]) but it seems to just give me an empty array.

what temp looks like after changing 75% before flatten:

```
[[      nan       nan       nan ...       nan       nan       nan]
 [      nan       nan 229.3249  ...       nan       nan       nan]
 [229.35771 229.32663 229.28688 ...       nan       nan       nan]
 ...
 [229.09474 229.14499 229.17618 ...       nan       nan       nan]
 [229.1779  229.27306 229.27135 ...       nan       nan       nan]
 [229.30244       nan 229.33873 ...       nan       nan       nan]]
```

suppose I want those nan to be in ndvi... shape is (600,400)

Thanks for reading this.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `mask = temp > T_25` followed by `ndvi[mask] = np.nan`?

Answer (score 0):

Your line `temp[temp > T_25] = np.nan` is almost correct. You just have to change the array that you're indexing to be `ndvi`:

```
ndvi[temp > T_25] = np.nan
```

Should do what you want.

You can also fold the calculation of `T_25` into the same line (assuming that `T_25` is the 25th percentile of the values in `temp`) like so:

```
ndvi[temp > np.percentile(temp, 25)] = np.nan
```